# $V$ is a normal rv with mean $0$ and variance $2$. Find the PDF of the function $Z = \frac{mV^2}{2}$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

How can I find the PDF of the function $Z=\frac{mV^2}{2}$, in terms of $\sigma$ and $\mu$, where $\mu$ is a constant greater than $0$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please use  [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference) For typing your question.  Also it is mandatory to add your own attempts, so that others are encouraged to help you.

Comment: Doesn't your title suggests that $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=2$?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hint. You can use a change of variable or the cdf method 
$$P(Z<z) = P\left(\frac{m}{2}V^2<z\right).$$
This method seems more popular.

Since the title says $\mu = 0, \sigma^2 = 2$, then I know that $$Y = \left(\frac{V}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2\sim \text{Gamma}(1/2,1/2).$$
From there, I can tell you that
$$Z = \frac{\sqrt 2 m}{2}Y \sim \text{Gamma}\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt 2 m}\right). $$
You can compare your work against this.

Answer (score 0):

If $X\sim N(0,1)$, then $X^2\sim\chi^2(1)$, where $\chi^2(1)$ is the [chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) with one degree of freedom.

If the random variable $Y$ has a density function $f_Y(y)$, then the random variable $cY$ has the density function
$$
f_{cY}(x)=\frac 1cf_Y\Big(\frac xc\Bigr)
$$
(see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables) for more details).